# Compact data structure for sorted array of pairs (integer, byte)?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, data-structures

I have quite a specific data set that I need to store in most compact way as a byte array. It is a live stream of integers that are constantly increasing, often by one, but not always one. Each integer value has a tag that is a byte value. There may be values with same value and tag, but I need to store only distincts. Only supported operations are adding new elements, removal and check if element exists - I keep this data set to check if some pair has been 'seen' recently.

Some sample data:

```
# | value | tag |
1 | 1000  | 0   |
2 | 1000  | 1   |
3 | 1000  | 2   |
4 | 1001  | 0   |
5 | 1002  | 2   |
6 | 1004  | 1   |
7 | 1004  | 2   |
8 | 1005  | 0   |
```

As I said this is a live stream, but I can tolerate storing only last few thousands. The goal is to make it as memory efficient as possible in the storage (and in RAM), operations can cost much.

If I had no tags, I could store ranges or values, (1000-1002),  (1002-1005) etc, there are usually about 5-6 values in a row without gaps. But the tags mess all this.

My current approach is to encode each value + tag pair in a few bytes - one byte for tag and 1 or more bytes for 'delta' from previous value.
This way I need to store first value, 1000 in above case, and than I store deltas - 0 for #1, #2, 1 for #4, 1 for #5, 2 for #6 etc.

Most deltas are small 1-10, so I can store it in one byte only - first bit is a flag if value is small enough to fit in 7 bits, if not - next 7 bits store a value of how may bytes delta occupies.

Maybe there is a better, more compact, approach?

Comment: Please give us the ranges of your integers and your tags.  Also please tell us whether there is anything else that could be taken advantage of.  For example, are these tags always increasing or at least non-decreasing within a sequence of identical ints?

Comment: ranges - most of them are 0 - 1000000. But sometimes Int.MaxValue may appear. But most usually I store an almost sequential array of values, differing by 1-2. Tags are 0-255, one byte, not ordered. But I can sort pairs with identicals ints by tag.

Comment: Absolute limits - value can be any non-negative int. Tag - may be any non-negative byte value, without any order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have only 127 different tag values, you could maintain 127 different tables, one for each tag, thus saving yourself from having to store the tags.  In each table you could still use your nifty trick with deltas.

Answer (score 0):

Let the pair `(value, tag)` where `value` is a `uint32` and `tag` is a `uint8` be a typical item stored in your data structure.

Use an associative array data structure that maps `uint32` to an array list of `uint16`. In C++ terms, the data structure is the following.

```
std::map<std::uint32_t, std::vector<std::uint16_t>>
```

Each array list stays sorted with distinct values and never exceeds a size of 2<sup>16</sup>.

Let `D` be an instance of this data structure. We store `(value, tag)` in the array list `D[value >> 8]` as `(static_cast<std::uint16_t>(value) << 8) + tag`.

The idea is basically that the data is paged. The most-significant 3 bytes of `value` determine the page, and then the least-significant byte of `value` and the single byte of `tag` are stored in the page.

This should exploit the structure of your data very efficiently because, assuming each page is holding many values, you're using 2 bytes per item.